# Embedding User + Password data for HTTP Basic Access Authentication in Querystring

Tags: http, authentication

We're trying to test an API that requires HTTP Basic Access Authentication credentials (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) in the request.

Ideally, we could just test the API using a web browser by putting all API parameters in the URL querystring, but we haven't yet found a way to encode the HTTP Basic Access Authentication credentials (username and password) in the querystring.

Does anyone know a way to do this?

Thus far, we've tried:

https://username:password@mydomain.com/

...without success.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`username:password@url` authentication has been disabled in many browsers for [security reasons](http://www.wisec.it/vulns.php?id=11).

For example in IE:

- [Internet Explorer does not support user names and passwords in Web site addresses (HTTP or HTTPS URLs)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/834489)

As far as I know, there is no way to circumvent this if this is blocked. It's possible that this can be turned of in Firefox using a setting in `about:config`. Or use some other browser that doesn't block it - I don't know which ones do and which don't.

Alternatively, consider building a quick web form that submits the option to a server-side language (e.g. PHP) that makes the request, or use a command line client like [`wget`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) to send the requests. The latter might even be easiest